# Creating a block such that the inside text has a specific indentation

Tags: indentation

I have a text like this:

Oss: word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word.

I'd like to create a block of text (the text after Oss:) with a specific indentation; for example like this one (the text shouldn't appear below Oss:):

Oss: {text}

........{text}

How can I get the above result?

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Such things would typically be done with the `itemize` environment.  See the `enumitem` package that allows these to be customized for your need.

Comment: You might also look at \hangindent, but only for a single paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe} % just for the example

\newenvironment{oss}
 {\begin{itemize}[label=\textbf{Oss:},leftmargin=*]\item}
 {\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{oss}
\lipsum[2][2-3]
\end{oss}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg thank you very much for your fantastic solution. Is there a way to avoid Oss: in bold?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Just remove `\textbf`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `wrapfig` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\noindent Normal text goes here

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}{5ex}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    Oss:
\end{wrapfigure}\noindent
word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word
word word word word

\noindent Normal text goes here

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can tweak values in square brackets(`[10]`) and in curly ones(`{5ex}`) to change the amount of wrapped lines and spacing after your text(«*Oss:*») respectively.

For instance, `\begin{wrapfigure}[2]{l}{3ex}...` will give you such a result.
[image]

Comment: Hello @antshar thank you very much for your solution.